# How to integrate D3@4.2.2 with Angular@2.0.0-rc5 and angular-cli@webpack

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angular-cli

I have been able to integrate D3@3.5.15 with Angular@2.0.0-rc5 and angular-cli@latest (the last version prior to webpack).

Shortly after the release of Angular@2.0.0-rc5, the angular-cli folks went all in up with a WEBPACK-centric release. I've spent quite a bit of time trying to get D3@4.2.2 to work in this environment with any success. Basically I have not been able to figure out how to expose D3 modules and functions in this environment.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards
Rodrigo

Answer (score 0):

I followed this to install d3: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#3rd-party-library-installation

Then in my chart component, I import d3 like this:

---

import * as d3 from 'd3';

---

d3 works; however, I am getting errors in the console:

---

Property 'axisBottom' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.

---

I am curious to see if you will get the same error messages...